# installing a keyed-entry door handle without switching latches?

Tags: doors, lock, latches

I have an internal door that currently has regular passage door handles without a lock and key, which I'd like to replace with keyed-entry door handles. Is it possible to replace just the handles and spindle without replacing the latch as well?

I’m aware that keyed-entry door handles are frequently used with a latch with a guardbolt, but is there an alternative which allows for use with a spring latch typical of passage door handles, like this one:
[image]
<sup>Image courtesy of Amazon.com</sup>

Is the guardbolt even needed for the functioning of the lock, or is it just added protection against bypassing the lock by moving the latch some other way?

*This question previously referred to an issue regarding removal of a latch. That was resolved in the comments, so the question has been rephrased to exclude that.*

Comment: A photo or two of what you have would be very helpful.

Comment: I can not quite discern what i am seeing in photo #2.  A more in  focus photo without a thumb would help.  Are all of the knob parts removed? have you tried to pry the latch out, use a screw driver in the knob hole to pry the latch outward ?

Comment: Magnification of crappy photo is still crappy. What about the questions i asked? It appears there is still something like a handle shaft in the knob hole behind your left hand fingers. How about a good photo of the knob hole.

Comment: @AlaskaMan If you mean pushing the latch out from the hole where the spindle goes, I didn't try that, nor do I think it would work with the faceplate in the way, given that it fits around the latch quite precisely. I've tried prying out the small bolt in the faceplate with a thin knife, but it didn't work and that the latch itself is in the way only makes it harder. Anyway, assuming it's not removable, is there any alternative without removing the latch?

Comment: Since it's a Gridlock latch set have you checked Gridlock products for a compatible keyed replacement. They may have one that will fit perfecly.

Comment: There is photo of a similar latch in the link below, that is not a bolt as you think it is.   There is something else holding in place.  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Gridlock+door+hardware&t=ffcm&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.doorfit.co.uk%2Farchitectural-hardware%2Fmedia%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Fcache%2F1%2Fimage%2F85e4522595efc69f496374d01ef2bf13%2Fg%2Fr%2Fgridlock-pb-latch_1_1.jpg  Lets see inside the knob hole.

Comment: It's a non security latch, you may find a privacy set for it.  but locking seems unlikely.

Comment: @AlaskaMan It seems you're right, that supposed 'bolt' is actually part of the latch. I tried pushing the latch out from the hole where the spindle goes, and it worked.

Comment: After the issue of removing the latch has been resolved, I've rephrased the question to ask generally whether switching latches is necessary or not, for the benefit of whoever might face a similar situation and want to keep their old latch

Comment: What is a "guardbolt"? Is that the same as a "[dead bolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_bolt)"?

Comment: Guardbolt??   A door knob latch and a Deadbolt are two different and seperate mechanisms.  Clarification is needed.

Comment: I take it you're referring to a *deadlatch* when you say your lock has a "guardbolt"?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to a 'deadlatch' or a 'deadlocking latch', see: https://www.gokeyless.com/blog/whats-the-difference-between-a-latch-and-deadbolt-and-which-is-better/ and http://www.thelockmanpublic.com/latches.htm